# variables sent between pages again?

Tags: php

I would like to use this concept on my webshop, but how can I send variables through?
(You know index.php? Page = test & variable = 22 // variable does not work)

```
$page = isset($_GET['Page'])? trim(strtolower($_GET['Page'])) :"front";

           $allowedPages = array(
           'front' => './include/webshop_frontshop.php',
           'logon' => './include/webshop_tjek_login.php',
           'test'  => './include/webshop_testside.php'

           );

     include( isset($allowedPages[$page]) ? $allowedPages[$page] : $allowedPages["front"] );
```

This link works fine!: nywebshop.php?Page=test

This link does not work (says the page does not exist): nywebsite.php?Page=test&item=5

Comment: You can use, post or session to store data and access on another php script ?

Comment: Do you actually use spaces in the url? If so, you shouldn't. And `'side' !== 'Page'`.

Comment: Please change your condition with this
$page = isset($_GET['Page'])? trim(strtolower($_GET['Page'])) :"front";

Comment: What does “not work”, and how? Please go read [ask].

Comment: No, No.. I do not use spaces in the link.
I have corrected code

Comment: This link works fine!: nywebshop.php?Page=test


This link does not work (says the page does not exist): nywebsite.php?Page=test&item=5

Answer (score -2):

Possible errors:

1) You use spaces in URL (in exemple you did)

2) In php you use $_GET['side'] - not $_GET['Page'] or $_GET['variable']

3) If you want to save variables in all pages after sending, you can use sessions:

```
$_SESSION['get_saved_param__Page'] = $_GET['Page'];
```

And it will be good to use standart

```
if {
  // code
} else {
  // code
}
```

As it much easier to read and you will spend most of the time in coding at reading your scripts, not writing.